# Comparing uuids for equality (in php)

Tags: php, uuid

What is the right way to check for equality of 2 uuids in PHP? I need to check 2 variables which have uuid values and act upon the result. I tried strcmp() but that did not yield the right value.

Thanks!
mmiz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strcmp() works fine for comparing strings. If you claim otherwise, you would need to provide a self contained fully running code sample to prove it. My point is, you've made a mistake elsewhere.

Personally, I would just use the strict (===) comparison operator though

```
if ($a === $b)
```

Comment: I"ll double check my work! Thanks for the suggestion of using strict comparison operator. I'll try that too.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion to use strict comparison did the trick!